# Reuse package.json version within file

Tags: maven, npm, gulp, package.json

I have a project which uses dependency having having version same as that of the project. So I would like to change the version only in one place and write something like below this in my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-child-app",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "description": "My Application",
  "dependencies": {
      "my-parent-app": %npm_package_version%
  }
}
```

Basically the child app is always supposed to have version in sync with the parent app. So any approach where I will have to change only one line (instead of two in usual scenario) when I have to upgrade to a newer parent-app would suffice.

**Note**: I am using `frontend-maven-plugin` to build the project as child-app is a module of Java Project. parent-app is also built in a same way but they are not in the same code repository so file referencing cannot be used.